# Code for vbYesNo

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below.  It deletes the record fine, but doesn't give the user the opportunity to not delete the selected record.  I need help adding a MsgBox vbYesNo and the code.  If it is vbNo, I would like to cancel the delete and return the user to TextBox6.  If it is vbYes, then delete the record and clear the userform.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range

On Error GoTo Err

'~~> Set the sheet where you want to search
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    '~~> Get the value which you want to search
    strSearch = TextBox6.Value

    '~~> Column A is Column 1 so Column B is 2. This is where we are searching
    '~~> xlWhole is used in the code below so that we find a complete match
    '~~> xlPart is supposed to be used when you are finding a partial match.
    Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    '~~> Check if we found the value
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        '~~> get the row of the cell where we found the match and delete it
        .Rows(aCell.Row).Delete          
    Else '<~~ If not found
        MsgBox "Customer Code not Found"
    End If
End With

Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

```
    If MsgBox("are you sure you want to delete " & aCell.Value & "?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "confirm deletion") = vbYes Then
        Rows(aCell.Row).Delete
        'clear user form here
        TextBox6.Value = ""
    End If
```

It's a little hard to provide specifics on clearing other elements and returning to the parent form as you've only identified `TextBox6`. More at [MsgBox function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range

On Error GoTo Err

'~~> Set the sheet where you want to search
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
'~~> Get the value which you want to search
strSearch = TextBox6.Value

'~~> Column A is Column 1 so Column B is 2. This is where we are searching
'~~> xlWhole is used in the code below so that we find a complete match
'~~> xlPart is supposed to be used when you are finding a partial match.
Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

'~~> Check if we found the value
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    '~~> confirm the row deletion
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete record """ & aCell.Value & """ ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    '~~> get the row of the cell where we found the match and delete it
    .Rows(aCell.Row).Delete
    End If
Else '<~~ If not found
    MsgBox "Customer Code not Found"
End If
End With

Exit Sub
Err:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```